# Programmatically change UITextField Keyboard type

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

Is it possible to programmatically change the keyboard type of a uitextfield so that something like this would be possible:

```
if(user is prompted for numeric input only)
    [textField setKeyboardType: @"Number Pad"];

if(user is prompted for alphanumeric input)
    [textField setKeyboardType: @"Default"];
```

Comment: i'd suggest you change the term `doozy` to something that's more commonly understandable.. keep in mind SO is an international site and not a North American one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically changing keyboard type on iOS does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619375/programmatically-changing-keyboard-type-on-ios-does-nothing)

Answer (score 380, accepted):

There is a `keyboardType` property for a `UITextField`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad including a decimal point
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // Optimized for entering Twitter messages (shows # and @)
    UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch,              // Optimized for URL and search term entry (shows space and .)

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Your code should read

```
if(user is prompted for numeric input only)
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

if(user is prompted for alphanumeric input)
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't stop a clever/deranged user from entering other characters. For example: If the Emoji keyboard was active *before* they tapped your number field, they're free to type smiley faces into it. There's nothing you can do about this, and it's definitely Apple's bug, but you **should** make sure your code doesn't crash if you get non-numbers in a number field.

Comment: Found out today, this is a property of the `UITextInputTraits` protocol, which `UITextField` adopts.

Comment: Is it possible to programmatically change keyboard type as UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation, for HTML input fields loaded in webview?

Comment: I created uitextfield programmatically in one project with respective keyboard type. this is woked few days ago. but now this is not worked. Not getting actual reason

Answer (score 86):

It's worth noting that if you want a **currently-focused** field to update the keyboard type immediately, there's one extra step:

```
// textField is set to a UIKeyboardType other than UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress

[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
[textField reloadInputViews];
```

Without the call to `reloadInputViews`, the keyboard will not change until the selected field (the [first responder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html)) loses and regains focus.

A full list of the `UIKeyboardType` values [can be found here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardType), or:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,
    UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch,
    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable
} UIKeyboardType;
```

Comment: This is useful information to know- I would suggest doing a Q&A-style self-answered question just to extract the information about the currently-focused field input change (that's what I was looking for when I found this answer)

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that calling reloadInputViews on the textfield that is currently NOT focused won't change keyboard type immediately. So better call [textfield becomeFirstResponder] first then [textField reloadInputViews]

Comment: It was `[textField reloadInputViews];` that I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Calling `reloadInputViews` also works for bespoke `UITextInput` implementations.

Answer (score 23):

Yes you can, for example:

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Answer (score 11):

```
    textFieldView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.PhonePad
```

This is for swift.  Also in order for this to function properly it must be set after the `textFieldView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 9):

to make the text field accept alpha numeric only set this property

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

If you are trying to change your keyboard type when a condition is met, follow this. For example: If we want to change the keyboard type from *Default* to *Number Pad* when the count of the textfield is 4 or 5, then do this:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextChange), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func handleTextChange(_ textChange: UITextField) {
 if textField.text?.count == 4 || textField.text?.count == 5 {
   textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
   textField.reloadInputViews() // need to reload the input view for this to work
 } else {
   textField.keyboardType = .default
   textField.reloadInputViews()
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeTwitter;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
_textField .keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a property for this called `keyboardType`.
What you'll want to do is replace where you have strings  `@"Number Pad` and `@"Default` with `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` and `UIKeyboardTypeDefault`.

Your new code should look something like this:

```
if(user is prompted for numeric input only)
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];

else if(user is prompted for alphanumeric input)
    [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

for people who want to use `UIDatePicker` as input:

```
UIDatePicker *timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 250, 0, 0)];
[timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_textField setInputView:timePicker];

// pickerChanged:
- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"d/M/Y"];
    _textField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[sender date]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the `UIKeyboardTypes` for Swift 3:

```
public enum UIKeyboardType : Int {

    case `default` // Default type for the current input method.
    case asciiCapable // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters
    case numbersAndPunctuation // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    case URL // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    case numberPad // A number pad with locale-appropriate digits (0-9, ۰-۹, ०-९, etc.). Suitable for PIN entry.
    case phonePad // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    case namePhonePad // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    case emailAddress // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).

    @available(iOS 4.1, *)
    case decimalPad // A number pad with a decimal point.

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    case twitter // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    case webSearch // A default keyboard type with URL-oriented addition (shows space . prominently).

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    case asciiCapableNumberPad // A number pad (0-9) that will always be ASCII digits.


    public static var alphabet: UIKeyboardType { get } // Deprecated
}
```

This is an example to use a keyboard type from the list:

```
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically change UITextField Keyboard type swift 3.0

```
lazy var textFieldTF: UITextField = {

    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.placeholder = "Name"
    textField.frame = CGRect(x:38, y: 100, width: 244, height: 30)
    textField.textAlignment = .center
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default //keyboard type
    textField.delegate = self
    return textField 
}() 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(textFieldTF)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the type of keyboard in Swift 4.2

```
// UIKeyboardType
//
// Requests that a particular keyboard type be displayed when a text widget
// becomes first responder. 
// Note: Some keyboard/input methods types may not support every variant. 
// In such cases, the input method will make a best effort to find a close 
// match to the requested type (e.g. displaying UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation 
// type if UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad is not supported).
//
public enum UIKeyboardType : Int {


    case `default` // Default type for the current input method.

    case asciiCapable // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters

    case numbersAndPunctuation // Numbers and assorted punctuation.

    case URL // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).

    case numberPad // A number pad with locale-appropriate digits (0-9, ۰-۹, ०-९, etc.). Suitable for PIN entry.

    case phonePad // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).

    case namePhonePad // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.

    case emailAddress // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).

    @available(iOS 4.1, *)
    case decimalPad // A number pad with a decimal point.

    @available(iOS 5.0, *)
    case twitter // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    case webSearch // A default keyboard type with URL-oriented addition (shows space . prominently).

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    case asciiCapableNumberPad // A number pad (0-9) that will always be ASCII digits.


    public static var alphabet: UIKeyboardType { get } // Deprecated
}
```