# Adding a UIKeyboard when a text field is clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to popup a keyboard when the user hits on a `UITextField`. I understand that this is done automatically. But the Keyboard i require should have the `.com` , `@` signs in it. Like in the Facebook application for iOS.

How can i add this Keyboard ? And what is it called ?

Comment: You can find your answer by visiting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type - set as UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer can be found here: [Programmatically change UITextField Keyboard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type)

To summarise...

You can change the keyboard type by doing the following:

```
[textField setKeyboardType:(TYPE)];
```

Replacing `(TYPE)` with one of the following:

```
UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress            // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
```

The one you are looking for (shows @ and .com) is `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`

Answer (score 1):

implement this

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddressL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you created your `UITextField` using interface builder, then navigate to the attributes inspector and change Keyboard to E-mail Address.

If you created it programmatically then add this

```
[yourTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

or

```
yourTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
```