# How to accept numbers in input field only in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

I am making an app i want that when user inputs any data then whatever user enter like if he enters a so it does not take this input and show nothing in textfield and if it enter any number then it should accept.

Comment: Why don't you use a numeric keypad then ? Make your keyboard type UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad

Comment: See the types of keyboard. You can set according to your need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following code should help you, this will not allow any other text to be entered in your text field other than numbers.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    static NSCharacterSet *charSet = nil;
    if(!charSet) {
    charSet = [[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet] retain];
    }
    NSRange strLocation = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
    return (strLocation.location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do u do this better give a keyboard style

```
[txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad]
```

or u can do it programatically :

```
NSString *nameRegex = @"[0-9]*";
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegex];
BOOL value = [nameTest evaluateWithObject:string];
if(value == YES)
    {
 // Do Somethings
    }
    else 
        {

    // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set keyboard type of Textfield as Numberpad.

Try this using code : (also u can set with Inter face builder on XIB property)

```
[txtFieldObj setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if (textField.tag==3)
{
    NSUInteger lengthOfString = string.length;
    for (NSInteger loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < lengthOfString; loopIndex++)
    {
        unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:loopIndex];
        if (character < 46 || character==47)
            return NO;
        if (character > 57)
            return NO;
    }
}
```

**Set tag to your textField.**

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSUInteger lengthOfString = string.length;
    for (NSInteger loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < lengthOfString; loopIndex++) {
        unichar character = [string characterAtIndex:loopIndex];
        if (character < 48) return NO; // 48 unichar for 0
        if (character > 57) return NO; // 57 unichar for 9
    }
```

this is the code should be written in textfield should change characters inrange