# Display the iOS Emoji keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

Can I toggle between the standard keyboard and the Emoji keyboard as the input view for a UITextView even if the user doesn't have the Emoji keyboard added as one of their keyboards in Settings?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't, I'm afraid. The Emoji keyboard is effectively a "language" setting that the user has to make and you cannot influence that.

The only thing you can change is the [keyboard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type).

You might want to experiment with a custom keyboard view, like [PMCustomKeyboard](https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards) if that feature is really important to you.

I've also found an interesting article that might help you: [Customizing the iOS keyboard](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to hear "no I can't," but that article did provide a lot of insight.

Comment: You can by subclassing UITextField. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382753/change-the-keyboard-layout-to-emoji