# Alt Button On Custom Keyboard in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode

It's the first time I'm creating a keyboard for iOS. I've created the first page with all the buttons but I don't understand how to add the second page.
For example: first page QWERTY, second page 123.
Is here anyone that can explain all the passages and functions/classes that I have to add on my codes and where precisely?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't built a custom keyboard personally but I would make seperate views for the "pages" of keyboards and just hide away and unhide the view of the keyboard you want to show when the user presses the "alt" button. You could have as many keyboards as you like with this method and have it pre-built in the backround so that it would function very quickly to swap between them. Or animate them as you like really as views are easy to slide around. Actually sounds like a lot of fun as I have often thought about building a keyboard that has alpha-numeric values all in one, which would make filling in details on a login screen much quicker/more convenient.

Comment: If it just the regular keyboard and NOT a custom one then check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301018/programmatically-change-uitextfield-keyboard-type